# How to use fetch in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, react-native-fetch-blob

i need help, i wanna get last 5 post from https://www.wired.com/category/security/ with react native but i dont know how i can do this, anybody help me, this is so important for me. i want to show on myscreen with flatlist, but i dont know how i can.

```
fetch(requestURL)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({
      data: data
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
  .done();
```

Comment: your base url is not returning data from api. This base url is not responding data from api

Comment: how can i fix it?

Comment: To fix this, you should know the exact request URL you're requesting. Where did you get this URL for API?